# Join two buffers into a single buffer

Tags: buffers, split

I'm looking for a way to:

- combine two buffers into single buffer using columns [1, winwidth] from left buffer and columns [1, eol] from right buffer.
- close buffer 2 so left with same contents in single left buffer. (It's should basically look like the window divider disappeared).

Visual example:
[image: Before State]

After running the cmd left with a single buffer with contents of the two buffers joined at the left buffer's window width
[image: After State]
Thank you for any suggestions. So I've tried starting in left buffer after copying the text in right buffer using visual block mode:

```
:set virtualedit=all    //for lines not the full width
:set nowrap             //don't want wrapping with new text
gg                      //go to first line
:norm! g$               //go to last column 
p                       //paste 
bd rightside.txt        //delete the no longer needed right buffer
```

This mostly works, but I'd like not have to block select the right side ahead of time, and ideally a better way to reference the right side buffer both to copy the text and close the buffer after. This is for a script that will split/rejoin a file right along the winwidth.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: updated with what I have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the other answers, was able to find a set of commands that does what I'm looking for:
Assume have the vertical split and focus in the left split.

```
:wincmd l     // move to right window
gg Ctrl v G$  // block select all of right buffer
y             // copy 
:wincmd h     // move back to left buffer
gg g$ l       // move one past last column in left window
p             // past contents of right buffer
0             // move to first column
:wincmd l     // move back to right window
:close        // close right window
```

Comment: To avoid needing to know the direction, you can use C-w p (or :wincmd p) for « previous window ».

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

- `:let &tw=&winwindth -1` set the text width to match the window width
- `ggVG` select all
- `gq` reformat introducing hard breaks
- `:wincmd w` switch to the other window
- `:let &tw=&winwindth -1`
- `ggVG`
- `gq`
- `:wincmd p` switch back to the original window
- `gg`<kbd>Ctrl v</kbd>`G$` select all in block mode
- `y` yank
- `:q` kill the window
- `gg`<kbd>Ctrl v</kbd>`G` select the first column
- `I`  <kbd>Esc</kbd> introduce 2 spaces
- `gg`
- `P` paste the content of the first window

Comment: The `set` commands don't make sense; you probably meant `:let`

Comment: Thank you.  those let and windcmd options may do the trick.  Will test and report back.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback :-)

Comment: Your solution slightly modified did exactly what I needed.   Thank you. I posted the solution I ended up using.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would:

1. disable Vim's "mouse" handling,
2. select the relevant text with my "mouse",
3. copy it with my terminal/system "copy" feature,
4. open a new buffer in Vim,
5. put the content from the system clipboard,
6. remove the separators.

Something like:

[image: example]

Comment: That's a cool use of the mouse selection to bust through vim's idea of text selection. I should have mentioned that this is for a script that will operate on thousand line file so I'm looking for a solution without manual selection. I'll update the description.